# Laravel - There is no existing directory at "logs" and its not buildable: Permission denied

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Laravel me da el siguiente error. ¿Qué sucede?

UnexpectedValueException
There is no existing directory at "/Users/usuario/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/htdocs/testosakidetza/storage/logs" and its not buildable: Permission denied

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias.

Comment: Llevas ya un tiempo por aquí, deberías saber que poner imágenes en lugar de texto plano no está bien visto y dificulta que la comunidad pueda ayudarte. Un saludo.

Comment: No lo sabía, lo siento. Los códigos que creo si que los pongo en texto plano, pero los mensajes de error en captura. Disculpa. Saludos.

Comment: ¿Has comprobado quien es el propietario de la carpeta storage y los permisos de acceso?

Comment: si he comprobado, y tiene los permisos 777. No comprendo el error. Saludos.